# Performance Test C# Code concludes with varying results each run

Tags: c#, .net, performance, performance-testing, .net-4.7.2

My goal is to compare the performance of many different C# implementations of the same thing. In the end I want to pick up the overall fastest implementation.
I'm using `StopWatch` to measure the time of each run, and also I'm using big enough input to enable the implementation to run longer and find significant differences in time between runs and to be sure they are not inside the margin of error.

The problem is that I find very big fluctuations even when the exact same code run. Sometimes if I reorder the test cases it will affect the result of specific test case by 50% increase in time which is outside the margin of error and completely changing the conclusion of which implementation is faster.
This is with the following code run before the test case itself and before the time is measured:

```
Thread.Sleep(500);
GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true, true);
GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Forced, true, true);
Thread.Sleep(500);
```

I understand that I can't rule out GC entirely, but still 50% fluctuations in time are too much. What can you suggest in addition to rule out as much variables as possible to find much more consistent and accurate time measurements of code runs?

Comment: Discard the first call to rule out JIT. You can use benchmark framework, but 50% accurancy is about as good as you can get anyway. There are way too many variables. I tend to pick the fastest time from more runs, differences smaller than 40% rate as inconclusive.

Comment: Consider running your tests multiple times and comparing the averages

Comment: We need to see a complete sample so we can reproduce it the issue and try to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) for such tasks. It cares about warming-up runs, about memory garbage collecting between runs, calculates mean value, standard deviation and error. It's powerful and designed for such tasks.

Answer (score 1):

fluctuations are because of operating system background works. **On the other words**, if you open `Task Manager` you will see that even if there is not any active program but `CPU usage` constantly changes between 2~3%. **Therefore**, There is not a constant situation. it looks like a Floating boat on the sea.

So for your test, Not only You should rely on your code but your should collect some system data and reduce **Error coefficient**. and provide a table looks like a below table.

```
Execution cycle | CPU usage %| RAM Usage GB| Hard Usage|

-----------------------------------------------------------
        100     |     2      |     1       |     2     |
        1000    |     5      |     0.75    |     1     |
        10000   |     10     |     0.5     |     2     |
        100000  |     11     |     1.5     |     4     |
        1000000 |     3      |     0.6     |     3     |
```

You have to reach to an equation like below:

```
Real Execution Performance = (g(CPU,RAM,Hard))*N mili-seconds 

N:= Nominal Execution Performance

Error coefficient `g(CPU,RAM,Hard)` related to CPU related to RAM related to Hard
```

For example: `Real Execution Performance = 0.7*(20,000) =14,000 mili-seconds`

Honestly: i was not able to reach **Error coefficient** and i'm looking for it.